# Run linux command "cat" inside a matlab script

Tags: linux, matlab, cat

In the bash script, it is possible to do following:

```
    cat > my.txt << EOF
         bla-bla-bla
         bla-bla-bla
         bla-bla-bla
    EOF
```

Is there any way I could execute this command inside a matlab m-file? I am thinking about `system`, but it seems it accept only simple one-string system commands.

Comment: Could you also use builtin Matlab functions for string concatenation?

Comment: The attractiveness of mentioned approach is that you save a formatted text in the regime "I see what I wrote" including all special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a system command that contains linebreaks with `sprintf`:

```
system_command = sprintf('cat > my.txt << EOF\n');
system_command = sprintf('%s\nbla-bla-bla', system_command);
system_command = sprintf('%s\nbliblablub', system_command);
system_command = sprintf('%s\nEOF', system_command);
system(system_command);
```